# LINQ use OfType() with given Type to get class

Tags: c#, linq

I want to filer a `List<IA>` of the type `IA` (an interface). Let's say I have the following structure:

```
interface IA {
    // Some definitions here...
}
class B : IA {}
class C : IA {}
```

I want to filter the list for `B` and `C` using LINQ. Normally, I would use the `myList.OfType<B>().ToList()` method but since I don't know in my method, what type I want to filter for, I need to find the base type of the list which I am doing with:

```
Type[] types = myList.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
// type[0] == typeof(B)
```

Now I want to do something like:

```
List<IA> filteredList = myList.OfType<type[0]>().ToList();
```

This doesn't work for the obvious reason that `OfType<>()` accepts only a class and not a type. My question is: How do I come from a type back to a class?

**Edit**: Changed the result I want to achieve from `List<type[0]>` to `List<IA>`.

**Edit2**: A working minimal example

```
class Program
{
    static List<IExample> exampleList;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        exampleList = new List<IExample>();

        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        exampleList.Add(a);
        exampleList.Add(b);

        List<IExample> anotherList = new List<IExample>();
        anotherList.Add(new A());

        FilterList(anotherList);
    }

    static void FilterList(List<IExample> anotherList)
    {
        Type t = anotherList.ElementAt(0).GetType();

        // This does not work:
        //exampleList.OfType<t>().ToList();

        // This does work:
        List<IExample> filteredList = exampleList.Where(item => item.GetType() == t).ToList();

        // The filtered List is then used for further processing ...
    }
}


interface IExample {}
class A : IExample {}
class B : IExample {}
```

Comment: Try to use `Type.IsAssignableFrom` in combination with the `Where`-extension method. Out of curiosity, do you have an example why you'd want to have a typed list like that ("`List<type[0]>`")?

Comment: Any reason not to make your method generic in the type you want to filter by? Also note that your terminology is fairly messed up - it's not about type vs class, it's about type vs expression... a type argument must be a type or another type parameter, not an expression of type `Type`.

Comment: Just do "Where(c => c is IA).Select(c => (IA)c).ToList()"

Comment: @Caramiriel I see, that this is not necessary and edited the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet The list I want to filter contains objects of different types and the method takes a parameter `List<IA>`. I want to only modify the elements of the list which are of the same type as the parameter. Do you have a link regarding the type vs expression topic?

Comment: @Freddy: Not really... it's just a fundamental aspect of the language. It's like you can't declare a variable with a type only known at runtime. It's still not clear what you mean, I'm afraid. It would help if you could provide a [mcve] of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm confused; how did you declare variable `myList` without knowing the element type at compile time?

Comment: And if you have a `List<IA>` in hand, why do you need to do this rigamarole at all in order to get a `List<IA>` out the other end?  Jon is right; it will be helpful if you give us an example that clearly shows what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am working on it and will provide a github link soon.

Comment: I updated the post with a working and minimal example.

Comment: You are trying to filter the list based on the type of the first element in the list?

Comment: Based on the first element of another list. Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following fragment seems to anwser the original question:

```
interface IA {}
class B : IA {}
class C : IA {}

var myList = new List<IA>{new B(), new C()};
var myType = myList[0].GetType();
var myFilteredList = myList.Where(elt => elt.GetType().Equals(myType)).ToList<IA>();
```

Comment: An interesting question is what to do for the case `class D : B {}... { new B(), new C(), new D()} ...`  Your code will not include the `D` in the list even though the `D` is an instance of `B`.

Comment: Eric Lippert, you're quite right. It seems there's always a quirk whenever one deals with object types directly, especially when inheritance is present.